# WebRequestMethods is being auto added to Desktop Application Project

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

In use of:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2022 (64-bit)
Version 17.5.2
```

I have several desktop applications I write for myself and while editing any of them I get the following error, randomly:

```
Error   CS0104  'File' is an ambiguous reference between 'System.Net.WebRequestMethods.File' and 'System.IO.File'
```

I scroll to the top of the class and delete the below using, to resolve it:

```
using static System.Net.WebRequestMethods;
```

I already use System.IO.File and this project has nothing to do with web, so I'm looking for a way to stop this from happening.  It's not a huge issue, just annoying.  Google search I found someone reporting it, but MS closed it out with "not enough information":
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/using-static-systemnetwebrequestmethods-keeps-gett/1696975

Anyone else have this issue or know a way to stop it?

EDIT, I found System.Net added to project, must of been added by something in Nuget, so I deleted it.  Since that time, now the following keeps auto adding to my classes with ListViews.

```
using static System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles.VisualStyleElement;
```

Throwing errors until I delete the "using" from the class.

```
Error   CS0104  'ListView' is an ambiguous reference between 'System.Windows.Forms.ListView' and 'System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles.VisualStyleElement.ListView'
```

There seems to be some serious AI $#!7 going on here.

Comment: It looks like a bug. Can you give me a way to reproduce, currently I can't find a way to reproduce. At present, when VS automatically inserts the namespace when it appears in the paste, you can turn off this function.

Comment: @JialeXue-MSFT not sure, seems to be random.   I have forms with a ListView on it, modify some code, sometimes, I get the CS0104 error.   I know to scroll to the top of the file and delete the auto inserted "using static ...".  Doesn't happen all the time, hasn't happened at all today, but happened 3 or 4 times yesterday.   Really odd behavior.  I dug through settings trying to find anything I can change to stop it in VS Configuration.   I found some "experimental" options, which I turned off.  That might be why it hasn't happened today, not sure.  Looked for the settings today, not there.

Comment: @JialeXue-MSFT it's happened a couple of more times since this post.  Different things each time.  Not always the same thing.   I'm assuming there is some kind of experimental option somewhere, causing this to occur.  I've been write code since 1985 in over 30 languages.   These days, there seems to be some AI work to "help" developers instead of letting them figure things out.  This will hurt development in the long run as it will never be as efficient.   For us old timers, we need an option to say, don't code for me!!   :)

Comment: Try turning off intellicode options like c# deep-learning. https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZuxs.png

Comment: @JialeXue-MSFT done.  Will let ya know how that goes.  Thanks.

Comment: I've exactly the same problem, "using static System.Net.WebRequestMethods;" are regularly inserted automatically, and I can't relate that to a specific action.  And in turns it breaks references to File...